# $1/(51 +u^2) + 1/(51 +v^2) + 1/(51 +w^2)$ inequality

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, tangent-line-method

I need to prove that $$1/(51 +u^2) + 1/(51 +v^2) + 1/(51 +w^2) \leq 1/20$$ given $u + v + w = 9$ and $u,v,w$ positive reals.

Using AM-HM inequality with $(51 +u^2, 51 +v^2, 51 +w^2)$ I arrive at

$(51 +u^2 + 51 +v^2 + 51 +w^2)/3 \geq 3/((1/(51 +u^2) +1/(51 +v^2) 1/(51 +w^2))$, $$or,$$

$1/(51 +u^2) +1/(51 +v^2)+1/(51 +w^2)  \leq 9/(51 +u^2 + 51 +v^2 + 51 +w^2)$

In order to take the next step, I need to estimate the RHS with an upper bound. Here is where I face the problem. With $(u+v+w)^2 \leq 3(u^2 + v^2 + w^2)$ from  C-S inequality and $u+v+w =9$ we get  $27 \leq  (u^2 + v^2 + w^2)$ which does not provide an upper bound. I tried several other inequalities, but each lead to a bound on the "wrong" side. Am I at all looking in the right direction?

Comment: Your second step is wrong. You proved reversed inequality, which does not help.

Comment: I have proved your inequality for all reals $u$, $v$ and $w$ such that $u+v+w=9$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote the following:

"Using AM-HM inequality with $(51 +u^2, 51 +v^2, 51 +w^2)$ I arrive at

$(51 +u^2 + 51 +v^2 + 51 +w^2)/3 \geq 3/((1/(51 +u^2) +1/(51 +v^2) 1/(51 +w^2))$, $$or,$$

$1/(51 +u^2) +1/(51 +v^2)+1/(51 +w^2)  \leq 9/(51 +u^2 + 51 +v^2 + 51 +w^2)$"

See please better, the last line should be:

$1/(51 +u^2) +1/(51 +v^2)+1/(51 +w^2)  \geq 9/(51 +u^2 + 51 +v^2 + 51 +w^2)$

You proved that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{51+u^2}\geq\frac{9}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(51+u^2)},$$ which does not help for the proof of your inequality.

By the way, the Tangent Line method helps.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\frac{1}{20}-\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{51+u^2}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{60}-\frac{1}{51+u^2}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(u-3)(u+3)}{51+u^2}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{(u-3)(u+3)}{51+u^2}-\frac{u-3}{10}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(u-3)^2(7-u)}{51+u^2}\geq0,$$ which is true for $\max\{u,v,w\}\leq7.$

Let $u>7$.

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{51+u^2}<\frac{1}{51+7^2}+\frac{2}{51}<\frac{1}{20}$$
and we are done!

Comment: @Parzifal I added something. See now.

Comment: Oh dear ... Thanks

Comment: @Parzifal You are welcome!

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg
This is a very elegant solution. I had a look at the tangent line method and worked through the steps. $(u-3)/10$ is the equation of the tangent in point $u = 3$. Looking at the second derivative of $f’’(u) = - 360(u^2-17)/(51+u^2)^3$ we see that the curvature changes sign at $u=+/-  \sqrt(17)$. Is it therefore permissible to subtract the tangent line beyond $ \sqrt(17)$? Thank you.

Comment: @Parzifal I just used that $\sum\limits_{cyc}(u-3)=(u-3)+(v-3)+(w-3)=0.$

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg: Interesting co-incidence since $(u-3)/10$ is the line equation of the tangent in $u = 3$. (Appreciate your time and help very much

Comment: @Parzifal Yes, of course! This is the cause, why this method named the TL method.

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg: Slowly it is dawning upon me - truly a beautiful solution!

Answer (score 2):

You're doing well. Note that you have $u^2+v^2+w^2$ in the denominator, and $1/x$ is a decreasing function. That means that
$$ \left( u^2+v^2+w^2 \ge \frac{(u+v+w)^2}{3} \right) \Rightarrow \left( \frac{9}{153+u^2+v^2+w^2} \le \frac{9}{153+\frac{(u+v+w)^2}{3}} \right)$$

EDIT: The answer is not correct, because the inequality $$\frac{1}{51+u^2} +\frac{1}{51+v^2}+ \frac{1}{51+w^2} \le \frac{9}{153+u^2+v^2+w^2} $$ is not correct. The correct one has $\ge$ sign, which doesn't help.

Comment: Dear me ... And just to make sure: Am I right to flip the ">" to "<" when taking the reciprocal of the HM-AM inequality? Thanks

Comment: Yes, for $x,y>0$: $(x \ge y) \Leftrightarrow (\frac{1}{x} \le \frac{1}{y})$.

Comment: Have you seen Michael Rozenberg's comment/answer? I am quite confused - can you help? Thanks.

Comment: He's wrong that the inequality that you proved doesn't help (it does, even  if it is only a step in the right direction), but the solution he proposes is also correct, even if a bit convoluted. The notation he uses $\sum_{cyc}$ may be unclear, it means $\sum_{u\in\{x,y,z\}}$.

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated.

Comment: @Adam Latosiński If you'll see down voting for your post, it's not mine.

Comment: @Adam Latosiński - Now Michael Rozenberg uses the "Tangent Line Method" that I do not know yet but will look at definitely. But could you guide me a bit on my approach if possible?

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg. You are right. I only focused on proving the last step, without checking whether the partial result is correct. I'd downvote my own answer if I could.

Answer (score 1):

$27  \leq (u^2+v^2+w^2)$ is exactly what you want. You want an **upper bound** on $9/(153+u^2+v^2+w^2)$, so you need a **lower bound** on the denominator, which you just found.